# Jquery option:selected not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to grab the selected option from the color but each time it returns the blank. When it goes to the cart page after it adds it to the car it returns the blank and not the selected color option.

```js
// Adds items to the shopping cart

handleAddToCartForm: function() {
  var self = this;
  self.$formAddToCart.each(function() {
    var $form = $(this);
    var $product = $form.parent();
    var price = self._convertString($product.data("price"));
    var name = $product.data("name");
    
    //Problem here
    var color1 = $("#color1 option:selected").val();

    $form.on("submit", function() {
      var qty = self._convertString($form.find(".qty").val());
      var subTotal = qty * price;
      var total = self._convertString(self.storage.getItem(self.total));
      var sTotal = total + subTotal;
      self.storage.setItem(self.total, sTotal);
      self._addToCart({
        product: name,
        price: price,
        qty: qty,
        color1: color1
      });
      var shipping = self._convertString(self.storage.getItem(self.shippingRates));
      var shippingRates = self._calculateShipping(qty);
      var totalShipping = shipping + shippingRates;

      self.storage.setItem(self.shippingRates, totalShipping);
    });
  });
},
```

```html
<div class="product-description" data-name="Rainbow" data-price="12">
  <h3 class="product-name">Rainbow</h3>
  <p class="product-price">$ 12</p>
  <p class="select-color">Color 1:
    <select id="color1">
      <option value="blank"></option>
      <option value="white">White</option>
      <option value="red">Red</option>
      <option value="orange">Orange</option>
      <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
      <option value="green">Green</option>
      <option value="blue">Blue</option>
      <option value="purple">Purple</option>
      <option value="pink">Pink</option>
      <option value="black">Black</option>
    </select>
  </p>
```

Comment: Are there any console errors? Do the other vars getting picked up ok?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the color inside the submit event handler. You are currently trying to do it before user has changed anything

Change

```
var color1 = $("#color1 option:selected").val();

$form.on("submit", function() {
```

To

```
$form.on("submit", function() {
    // get color when user submits . Need to also do some validation
    var color1 = $("#color1 option:selected").val();
```